# Is there an equivalent of the Java Sound API?

Tags: scala

Is there an equivalent in Scala of the Java Sound API, to play sounds, or should I use the Java one??

Answer (score 6):

I'd go and use the Java Sound Api. At the time of writing this (October 2011) [alternatives](http://code.google.com/p/squier/) aren't mature enough.

When interacting with an existing Java Api from scala, you'll find [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions%24.html) pretty useful.

Good luck!

Comment: +1. Fwiw, `JavaConverters` are usually preferred over `JavaConversions`. `JavaConversions` pull in too many implicits in the scope, leading too all sorts of nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [scala-midi](http://code.google.com/p/scala-midi/).

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the author and I'd like other user's feedback.