# Playing wav files in scala

Tags: scala, audio, wav

I'm trying to play a .wav file from my scala 1.9.2 program. The only way I can see to do it is to import sun.audio. Is there a better way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863860/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-java-sound-api

Comment: Falling back on java is a good choice here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.net.URL
import javax.sound.sampled._

val url = new URL("http://mywebpages.comcast.net/jdeshon2/wave_files/jad0001a.wav")
val audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url)
val clip = AudioSystem.getClip
clip.open(audioIn)
clip.start
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have audio in bytes

```
def play(bytes: Array[Byte]) {
  import sun.audio.{AudioPlayer, AudioStream}
  val audioStream = new AudioStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
  AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream)
}
```